# How to group and sort list of lost in python?

Tags: python

I want to know how can I group and sort the following:

```
A = [ [ 1,3.5] ,[2,4.5], [5,67], [4,56] ,[2,2] ,[1,45] ]
```

How can I eliminate the lesser value(keep the maximum alone) for repeated items. The result should be

```
B = [ [ 1 ,45] ,[2,4.5], [4, 56], [5,67]]
```

Please let me know how to do this. I am new to python.

Comment: How do you determine that you want to keep `[1, 45]` rather than `[1, 3.5]`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice "eliminate the lesser value" I think means "keep the maximum"

Comment: The maximum value between 45 and 3.5 with respect to 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way is to use a dictionary to track the maximum value per first element, then rebuild your list from the dictionary:

```
maximums = {}
for key, val in A:
    if maximums.get(key, float('-inf')) < val:
        maximums[key] = val

B = [[key, val] for key, val in maximums.items()]
```

This gives you a O(N) linear time algorithm, as opposed to using `sorted()`, a O(NlogN) algorithm.

Comment: @behzad.nouri: neither of which applies to Python code.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest first writing a function that compares two lists according to your definition. Then you can use this function with `filter()`.

Comment: Not very helpful without showing how that function would be used, and also not very efficient as the function would require testing every element in `A` against every other element in `A` to find those that have a matching first value.